# How to say "he was waiting long time but not ... (did not reach goal)"?

Tags: translation

How to say "he was waiting long time but not ... (did not reach goal)"?

I have problem with some translation I want express such expression that "someone" is waiting long but not finished it since something not occurs.

Example "I was waiting whole day for sun but did not ..."? (reach?, wait?).

I am not native speaker and have problem to find this simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe ...

> In vain

... might be suitable. It's hard to tell from the example. You were waiting for the sun but then darkness fell. You were waiting for the sun but it did not appear. You were waiting for the sun but something else happened.

> You were waiting for the sun but it was in vain.

Comment: I want translate such Polish phrase but maybe there is not equivalent: "Czekałem na coś cały dzień, ale się nie doczekałem". What could be expressed in English "I was wating whole day but did not live/reach/wait" but not sure what is the natural meaning. I feel that "did not live" for me is strange but It could be wrong feeling - "did not wait" is very strange for me too - think about "did not reach" - I am not native speaker so could not feel it right. If you need more information ask again.

Comment: BTW brute force translation is ""Czekałem na coś cały dzień, ale się nie doczekałem" == "I am waiting whole day but ?I am not done (waiting)?" other examples "I am waiting for you but I am not meet you ?in this case: I am not done (waiting) == not meet you?".

Comment: From your examples - It looks that in English there is no abstract construction like "nie doczekałem się" so you use rather "I am waiting for something but not did not SPECIFIC VERB = (i.e. appear)".

Comment: @Chameleon Perhaps "I've been waiting all day for X, and I'm still waiting" would meet your need; but it's difficult to cast into the past tense. If your context has a terminus, you might try "I had been waiting all day for X, and I was still waiting when Y occurred."

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you very much for suggestion. The last part has little different meaning maybe there is no translation. You suggest "I've been waiting all day for X, and I'm still waiting" - in 2nd part I am not meaning that I am still waiting but that "waiting is done and result is failure" - not sure that I could say "I was waiting whole day and I did not wait" - it is strange for me but maybe it is valid translation not know it - I am not meet this usage and is very strange in Polish but could good in English.

Comment: @Chameleon Perhaps "I waited all day and finally gave up [at 8 o'clock or whenever]" would work?

Comment: I'm afraid you are approaching it all wrong, @Chameleon. Translation does not work that way, you cannot hope to translate your sentence word for word in whatever language you please. You can have an exact translation of *doczekałem* into another Slavic language, like e.g. Russian; but not into a Germanic one, like English or German, because they are simply wired completely differently from Polish. For these, Teylyn's answer is exactly right. Take it and run with it.